# How to restrict access to pages based on user type in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a basic question which can be useful for new Django developers.

I created my own UserProfile in Django. This UserProfile has a specific field called 'type'. This field can have two values (until now maybe more in the future) : Male - M / Female - F :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

GENDER = (
    (M, 'Male'),
    (F, 'Female'),
)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    type = models.CharField( max_length=2,
                             choices=GENDER,
                             default='F')
```

Basically, I wanted to allow access to restrict access or to adapt page content depending on user Type. Until now, I used a really basic and beginner approach which is to test user type in a view and then process the page:

```
def OnePage(request):
    if request.user.type == 'M':
        ....
    else if request.user.type =='F':
        ....
```

Then I also need to adapt the template rendered depending on user type: a male user will not have the same profile page that a Female User.

I am sure there are better ways to do this but as a Django beginner I am quite lost with all of Django possibilities. So if you have any best practices to implement this please tell me (obviously I would like a DRY code I could use on every view!)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution could be to change the base template name depending on the user type:

```
@render_to('some_template.html')
def some_view(request):
    base_template = 'base_%s.html' % request.user.profile.type
    # …
    return {
        'base_template': base_template,
    }
```

And in your template :

```
{% extends base_template %}
{% block some-block %}
…
{% endblock %}
```

If you need to do this on every view, you could use a middleware to set this value.

Comment: What do you mean by a middleware ?

Comment: [It's in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs)

Answer (score 7):

To restrict access, use the [user passes test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test) decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

male_only = lamda u: u.type == 'M'
female_only = lamda u: u.type == 'F'


@user_passes_test(male_only)
def myfunc(request):
   pass

@user_passes_test(female_only)
def myotherfunc(request):
   pass
```

Answer (score 0):

To add extra data to User see

[Storing additional information about users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users)

Then add the profile to your context and you can use {{profile}} variable in your template

```
{% if profile.type == "F" %}
    blah, blah
{% else %}
    blah, blah
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yes that's what I did until now. But is there a way to not repeat myself on every page where I need to do this process ? Like a decorator or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, if you need to use very different html for different genders, you can try this approach:

```
def gender_filter(func):
    def _view(request,*args,**kwargs):
        res=func(request,*args,**kwargs)
        if request.user.get_profile().type=='F':
            res.template_name='template_f.html'
            res.context_data['gender']='female'
        elif request.user.get_profile().type=='M':
            res.template_name='template_m.html'
            res.context_data['gender']='male'
        return res.render()
    return _view

@gender_filter
def my_view(request):
    t=TemplateResponse(request,'template_f.html',{...})
    return t
```

So instead of returning Http resonpse in views, you can make them return [TemplateResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/template-response/) objects and use decorators to change templates, add in general context, and them convert them to HttpResponse.

Or something like a permission check:

```
def gender_only(gender):
    def _dec(func):
        def _view(request,*args,**kwargs):
            if request.user.get_profile().type==gender
                return func.render(request,*args,**kwargs)
            else:
                raise Exception("You do not have the right gender")
        return _view
    return _dec

@gender_only('F')
def my_view(request):
    ...
    return render_to_response('template.html',{...},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```