# Django: Block access to specific users in one app

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-apps, django-middleware

I'm building an Django project `demonstration` that has in its constitution 3 apps (app, blog, frontend)
[image]

***The challenge*** I'm facing is the following:

I want to **limit access to the app `app` to allow only registered users**.

In other words, restrict access to all the pages in `app` django app.

After doing some research, stumbled accross the following links:

1. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164069/best-way-to-make-djangos-login-required-the-default)
2. [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597864/how-to-restrict-access-to-pages-based-on-user-type-in-django)
3. [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017542/restrict-access-to-all-the-pages-in-a-django-app)

The answer in [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164069/best-way-to-make-djangos-login-required-the-default) seems the easier to implement.

Still, I'm having some problems doing it, as I have little experience working with Middleware in Django.

*Asked there in the comments*:

'I want to limit the access of one app, called app, if the user doesn't have login. The middleware RequireLoginMiddleware class should be placed where?'

but no reply yet so far and I don't seem to find a way to cross this.

Can anyone explain me what I need to do to **Restrict access to all the pages in a django app to allow only registered users**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to fix:**

Inside of `views.py`, from the `app` app directory,
added the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
```

and, right before calling the view:

```
@login_required(login_url="/admin/") #location where users are going to be able to do the login
def profile(request): #view
```

**This means**: once the user is not logged on and tries to access the view, he/she/it will be redirected to the login screen

Comment: Don't hardcode urls (use `reverse()` instead). Also, you don't need to specify the login_url in each and any call to `login_required`, if you don't it will use the one specified in your settings (which is usually what you want).

Comment: Tried to implement `reverse`and `reverse_lazy`.
Didn't manage to do it yet and tbh I'm not seeing the importance of it unless you explain better.
About the other side, it was made on purpose just to show how that can be done to whatever url we want

Answer (score 2):

Where your middleware lives is up to you, the only thing that matters is that it's in your `sys.path`.

Also note that the middleware in [Best way to make Django's login_required the default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164069/) is relying on hard-coded urls (well, hardcoded in the `settings` at least), which is a DRY violation. This could be solved by using `reverse_lazy` for each url of your `app` app but at this point you'll be faster just decorating your `app` views with `login_required`